# How to calculate MD5 hash in DB2 9.5

Tags: db2

Is there a function/package available in DB2 9.5 to calculate MD5 hash? Something similar to Oracle's `DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.MD5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in function to do this, but you can certainly create your own User Defined Function (UDF).

This Developerworks article contains an implementation: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0407tessarek/#UDFs

Comment: I dont/cant create UDF because of some client environment restrictions. Thats the main reason I'm looking for in-build functions of DB2. If I've to write custom code, I'd rather write in Java as our product is developed in Java and use Java's `MessageDigest`. None the less thanks for the suggestion @Ian

Comment: Yes, unfortunately there is no built-in function.  If you can't create a UDF, then sounds like your plan of doing it within the app is a better choice.

Comment: Accepting Ian's answer as that is what most nearest solution I can have. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is `GET_HASH_VALUE` function in DB2 9.7 part of `DBMS_UTILITY` system module.

Here is link from documentation :

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0055167.html

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Vishal, thanks for the link, but I want something similar for DB2 9.5 and not 9.7. I know 9.7 is lot improved in terms of getting near to SQL standards etc, but unfortunately I'm stuck with 9.5 because of some clients dont want to upgrade to 9.7 or even better 10