# Is there any MD5 function in DB2 version 10

Tags: db2, md5

The following post: [How to calculate MD5 hash in DB2 9.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565043/how-to-calculate-md5-hash-in-db2-9-5) from 2012 and concerns DB2 9.5.
I have to hash data using MD5 in DB2 database to compare it with data from SQL Server database. SQL Server has a function

```
HASHBYTES('MD5', @HashThis);
```

Does a similar function already exist in DB2 from version 10?

Comment: If you have a solution for DB2 9.5 I'm pretty sure that works for 10.0 as well.

Comment: for 9.5 there is no ready MD5 function. I thought that maybe there is some for version 10.

Comment: ...why are you trying to get an MD5 hash?  What are you using it for?

Comment: There was done a migration of database from db2 to SQL Server. There are differences, unmatched, missing data after that migration. There is a request to use MD5 to hash data in a table from DB2 database and from table from SQL Server database. Then there is a plan to compare the results to find out what is the scale of the problem. That's why I need to get MD5 function.

Comment: That won't be reliable, unless you convert query output on both sides to identically formatted strings, in which case you don't need MD5 as you can simply `diff` sorted output.

Comment: what do you mean by "diff sorted output" ? export data to files and then compare? if yes, then it is not a good idea, there is too much data, it is expected to limit amount of data, that's why using MD5 would help here

Comment: If you just want to know what rows might be missing you could potentially just export the primary keys.  Unless your databases were set to use the same encoding (DB2 defaults to Unicode), character data will (potentially) have different byte patterns.  I'd imagine most tools ([like the one Microsoft makes](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45296)) would be able to spit out a report, if it was managing the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately DB2 does not include hashing functions. But you can have a look at my open source project on github:

[UDFs and SPs for DB2 to generate and validate hashes](http://tessus.github.io/db2-hash-routines/)

There are 2 md5 routines included: one for seeded md5 hashes (`apr_md5`) and one for static md5 hashes (`php_md5`).